# what wrong with my SQL statement of condition insert in mysql?

Tags: mysql

There:

When I try to do data insert data in my table without any duplicated record, I use both of following SQL statement. But none of them work for me. My verion of mysql is 5.1.33-community.

```
SELECT @nextID := IFNULL( MAX( N_KEY ), 0 ) + 1
  FROM SYS_DICT
 WHERE N_CAT = 1;

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) AS N_COUNT
     FROM SYS_DICT
    WHERE N_CAT=1 AND C_VALUE='welcome'
   ) <= 0
THEN
  INSERT INTO SYS_DICT
    VALUES( 1, @nextID, 1, 100, 'welcome');
END IF
```

or

```
SELECT @nextID := IFNULL( MAX( N_KEY ), 0 ) + 1
  FROM SYS_DICT
 WHERE N_CAT=1;

INSERT INTO SYS_DICT
  VALUES ( 1, @nextID, 1, 100, 'welcome')
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT N_KEY
      FROM SYS_DICT
     WHERE N_CAT=1 AND C_VALUE='welcome'
  );
```

Any hint?

Comment: "none of them work" is not a proper error description you have to be more specific.

Comment: Additionally: Using `max` to generate unique ID values *will* fail eventually in a multi-user/multi-transactional system. Don't do it. Use an auto_increment instead.

Comment: Thanks,a_horse_with_no_name. For some reason, this field can not be a auto_increment field. This code is a maintenance code and will not be run in multi-user mode.